# No outlier detection in boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to plot boxplots of dataframes (see sample code below). What I'm wondering is: How can I disable the detection of outlier? I don't want to remove them, I just want a plot which visualizes the data by marking 0%, 25%, 50% and 75% of the datapoints without considering any criteria for outliers etc.

How do I have to modify my code to achieve this? Can I change the outlier detection criteria in a way that it behaves like disabled?

I would be very grateful for any help and if there is already another threat about this (which I didn't find), I would be happy to get a link to it.

Many thanks!
Jordin

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])

plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(df.values)
plt.show()
```

EDIT:

[image: The outlier on the top right side is marked as an outlier]

I would like to include this outlier when drawing the whiskers and not just not show it.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "detection of outlier"? a boxplot doesn't detect outliers. It plots the median, quartiles and a CI

Comment: For example if you execute the code above, an outlier is marked with a circle. As far as I know, this outlier is not taken into account when drawing the borders of the quartiles (the outlier doesn't lie within the whisker). Thus, I would like to just plot the quartiles, median etc. without neglecting any point which is considered as an outlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `whis` parameter.

For the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html):

> **whis** : float, sequence, or string (default = 1.5)
>
> As a float, determines the reach of the 
>   whiskers to the beyond the first and third quartiles. In other words,
>   where IQR is the interquartile range (Q3-Q1), the upper whisker will
>   extend to last datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR). Similarly, the lower
>   whisker will extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - whis*IQR.
>   Beyond the whiskers, data are considered outliers and are plotted as
>   individual points. Set this to an unreasonably high value to force the
>   whiskers to show the min and max values. Alternatively, set this to an
>   ascending sequence of percentile (e.g., [5, 95]) to set the whiskers
>   at specific percentiles of the data. Finally, whis can be the string
>   'range' to force the whiskers to the min and max of the data.

Add it like so:

```
df.boxplot(whis=99)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

If you add `sym=''` inside your plot function I think you will get what you ask for:

[image: boxplot]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])

df.boxplot(sym='')
```

Comment: The problem is: With your solution, the outliers are just not plotted, but I want to include them into the whiskers,

Comment: Or is there like any other type of diagram which is suited for my purpose?